# Using dfs and calculate_feature_matrix?

Tags: data-science, featuretools

You could use `ft.dfs` to get back feature definitions as input to `ft.calculate_feature_matrix` or you could just use `ft.dfs` to compute the feature matrix. Is there a recommended way of using `ft.dfs` and `ft.calculate_feature_matrix` for best practice?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a situation where you might use either, the answer is to use `ft.dfs` to create both features and a feature matrix. If you're starting with a blank slate, you'll want to be able to examine and use a feature matrix for data analysis and feature selection. For that purpose, you're better off doing both at once with `ft.dfs`.

There are times when `calculate_feature_matrix` is the tool to use as well, though you'll often be able to tell if you're in that situation. The main cases are:

1. You've loaded in features that were previously saved
2. You want to rebuild the same features on new data